# how to solve $f(y)u_x+u_y = cu$ where $u(x,0) = g(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $c$ be a constant and $f,g$ are continuous functions. Then im asked to solve $f(y)u_x+u_y = cu$ where $u(x,0) = g(x)$ ?

I end up with parametrization $\frac{dx}{f(y)} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{cu}$.

Then i solve $\frac{dx}{f(y)} = \frac{dy}{1}$ which i write $f(y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ and by the chain rule i obtain $\frac{d}{dx}(F(y)) = 1$ and then i integrate both sides $F(y) = x+c_1$.

Then i solve $\frac{du}{ds} = cu$ which have a solution $e^{cy}\phi(c_1)$ so the general solution should be $e^{cy}\phi(F(y)-x)$. Then i try to apply the initial condition to the general solution, but i get stuck here $u(x,0) = \phi(F(0)-x) = g(x)$.

So my question: if this is at all correct how to proceed? If not suggest another way.

Comment: You've done everything correctly, assuming $F(y) = \int f(y) dy$; now you have $\phi(x) = g(F(0) - x)$ and hence $$u = e^{cy} \phi(F(y) - x) = e^{cy} g(F(0) - F(y) + x)$$

Comment: $\phi\Big(F(0)-x\Big)=g(x) \implies \phi(x)=g\Big(F(0)-x\Big)$, so now you know $\phi$!

Comment: ok i was able to verify the solution with change of variable. thanks for the help